# All videos stutter

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, video, vlc, youtube

**I'm using Ubuntu 20.04, 64 bit, Desktop.**

When I watch a video, it stutters very noticeable. This happens with every video on every plattform (youtube, disney+, amazon video etc.) also with DVD's or if I watch a video that I recorded with my smartphone and so on.

**This is a example on how it looks like: The video stutters (very noticeable if you have a look at the statue of liberty in the video):**

*(This i not a recording stutter, it is exactly this way when I watch a video)*

https://youtu.be/soLJwuoufU0

I had a look at this one: https://dragoshmocrii.com/ubuntu-20-04-stuttering-animations-video/
But I have no such extensions installed. To make sure, I deactivated "Ubuntu AppIndicators", but did not solved it.

Any ideas?

Comment: what browser are you using? did you turn on hardware acceleration in the browser's settings? that is likely the issue

Comment: Consider reinstalling / reconfiguring your graphics driver. Have a look at your CPU load while playing the video. Maybe are not using hardware transcoding and your CPU is not capable enough to handle the frames seamlessly.

Comment: @Esther I tried Firefox and Chromium on two differnt systems, (GTX 1060 and GTX 1660 super). The issue appears in both browsers on both systems. One of the system (GTX 1660 super) was a fresh installation. 

Hardware acceleration is enabled in Firefox.

Comment: @PasWei CPU rate is fine < 20% overall
I tried with two different drivers, on two differnt systems and with two different gpus (see above).

Comment: Do you have Nvidia drivers installed? Which version? And is Secure Boot disabled in UEFI?

Comment: @ChanganAuto I tried 470 and 515 driver. Also noveau.
On one system Secure Boot is disabled, on the other one it is activated.